# Leaking "Thread-n" strings in python

Tags: python

I am trying to debug a memory leak in a python 2.4 ThreadingUnixStreamServer based application.
It appears that I am leaking memory on every request to the server.
Trying to debug it, I used the gc module to count the number of objects between consecutive calls to "handle", and received the same number.
However, when I checked the number of strings, I noticed that it grew between requests.
When I diffed the list of strings between calls, I noticed that I had a new string created "Thread-n" (where "n" is a running number, e.g. "Thread-3", "Thread-4", etc.).
I assume this has something to do with the fact that the server spawns a new thread with a new name for each request, but it is not clear to me why the old names were not cleaned from memory.  I have checked and seen that there is no increase in the number of concurrent threads, so it does not appear as if I am leaking actual threads.
Any idea how I can find the references to these strings, or, alternatively, any guesses on what may cause this leak, or how I can investigate it?

Thanks.